# Seed Database When Deploying to Azure Website

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to Seed (using an external recource, which is  CSV file) the Azure SQL database associated with an Azure Website.

I am able to Seed the database in development environment using [EF Migration Seed method and a CSV file](http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2014/03/18/seeding-entity-framework-database-from-csv.aspx) as defined as follows in the Migration.cs file. Note: the CSV file in the project in Visual Studio are set to the Build Action to Embedded Resource.

```
 public void SeedData(WebApp.Models.ApplicationDbContext Context)
        {
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            string resourceName = "WebApp.SeedData.Name.csv";
            using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    CsvReader csvReader = new CsvReader(reader);
                    csvReader.Configuration.WillThrowOnMissingField = false;
                    var records = csvReader.GetRecords<Products>().ToArray();

                    foreach (Product record in records)
                    {                            
                          Context.Products.AddOrUpdate(record); 
                    }
                }
            }
            Context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

When I deploy to Azure from VS2013 and select Execute Code First Migration, the database does not get seeded.

**UPDATE**
This is now working. After I did a clean build, then built the project, and then deployed the the web site with selecting Execute Code First Migration.

Comment: Can you kindly explain what you mean be a "clean build" I am running into a similar problem. My seed method is quite heavy as I pull data from multiple online services to populate the apps DB. When I run it locally, it takes almost half an hour to complete, But when I access my methods via API after deploying, I get nothing.

Comment: In visual studio, under build menu select "clean build"